# how can i test if context variable is undefined on watson dialog condition?

Tags: watson-conversation, watson-dialog

hi can i am creating a watson dialog bot, and i have a context variable that control the flow in some situations...

i need to test if a context variable was already defined (exists) in that moment... anyone knows how to do that?

[image]

i tried already:

```
$intent == empty
$intent == null
$intent == "null"
```

anyone knows?

Answer (score 11):

If I understand your question correctly, you can simply do **!$intent**. If it doesn't exist in that moment it should return false, opposite of that being true.

Here's an image to further explain it. You'll see there is only one item in manage context (only the timezone item) and my node is firing as expected.
 [image]

Comment: Please mark the answer if this worked for you. Happy to help!

Comment: This is a life saver! I have been searching for this a day. :D